# How to extract the n-th elements equal to a value from a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, max

I'm trying to obtain the nth elements from a list of tuples in python equal to a certain value

I have a much larger list of something like this

```
num = [('A15', 2, 'BC', 721.16), ('A21', 3, 'AB', 631.31), ('A42', 4, 'EE', 245.43)]
```

I wish to extract only the tuples with the 2nd element of the tuple equal to a given value i.e. 2 in this example and from those find the largest 4th element

Currently my code looks like the following

```
for ((x[1] for x in num) = 1):
    num_max = max(num_list,key=lambda item:item[3])
```

the problem's something to do with setting the list comprehension equal to a value as that's what's giving me a syntax error

Apologies if this has already been answered but I couldn't find it

Comment: that is not a valid for loop in python

Comment: `max([i for i in num if i[1] == 2], key=lambda x: x[3])`

Comment: `max([i for i in x if i[1] == 2], key=lambda x: x[3])[3]` if you only want the element

Comment: More importantly though, what is `for ((x[1] for x in num) = 1):` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
In [1]: num = [('A15', 2, 'BC', 721.16), ('A21', 3, 'AB', 631.31), 
               ('A42', 4, 'EE', 245.43),('A15', 2, 'BC', 856.16)]
In [2]: max((i for i in num if i[1] == 2),key=lambda  x:x[3])
Out[2]: ('A15', 2, 'BC', 856.16)
```

Comment: Why downvote ? It's greatful to describe the reason. :)

Comment: Upvote from me. The main thing I'd change is use a generator expression instead of building a list, i.e. replace square brackets with regular ones.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, using `filter` and `max` for example:

```
result =  max(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 2, num_list), key=lambda x: x[3])
```

As commented by @chrisz, but instead of a `list` use a `generator`:

```
result = max((i for i in x if i[1] == 2), key=lambda x: x[3])
```

Note: If using **`python2`** consider using [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) instead of `filter` to avoid extra memory.